# Update website automatically via database

Tags: database

So I have created a database for my church website that the admin can upload our current sermons easily and it update the website automatically based on what the date is.

Use Case:
Admin Uploads Sermon 3 months before it starts --> No Change on the website --> 3 Months pass and it’s the first Sunday that sermon is airing —> Website updates to show the sermon.

openarms.site down at the bottom is where I want it to be viewable, showing the previous 10ish sermons with the most current one being at the left.

I’ve successfully made the code to upload the sermons to the database but I am not sure where to start on the website updating it’s self. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Well, normally a web site reads from the database, not the other way round... A database is a storage tool, not an application server.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which language you're writing your website in. The basic idea is you need to have different views in your database and your website only serves the most current view and in the database the views are updated at regular intervals based on whatever update logic you have.

Comment: When you say "view" do you mean specifically the "CREATE VIEW" view? Or an MVC-style view? Normally you'd assemble the latter by querying the database but I suppose you could move all the actual logic to a SQL view.

Comment: Yes I was talking about the sql view here.